# Líneas y trazos indeseados al dibujar con el dedo en pantalla usando Paint() y Canvas()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

me encuentro realizando un pequeño proyecto en **Android 5** donde necesito poder dibujar con mi dedo sobre la pantalla libremente, en internet encontré un ejemplo el cual apliqué y funciona bien, excepto por un detalle, en algunas ocaciones cuando dejo de dibujar y empiezo nuevamente el espacio que existe entre ambos trazos es unido con una línea recta inmediatamente.

Para esto estoy usando **Paint()** y **Canvas()**

**El código es el siguiente:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Vista vista = new Vista(this);
    setContentView(vista);
}
class Vista extends View {
    float x = 50;
    float y = 50;
    String accion = "accion";
    Path path = new Path();
    public Vista(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if ("down".equals(accion))
            path.moveTo(x, y);
        if (accion.equals("move"))
            path.lineTo(x, y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            accion = "down";
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            accion = "move";
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}}
```

Adjunto algunos ejemplos del problema:

[image: Ejemplo 1]

La línea central recta no debería aparecer cuando intento dibujar dos trazos, vemos que se une la parte final del primer trazo y la parte inicial del segundo.

Esto sucede cuando intento realizar un circulo:

[image: Ejemplo 2]

En ocaciones se crea una línea recta desde la esquina superior izquierda hasta el punto donde inicio a dibujar.